# Launch third part app

Tags: android, android-intent

I am trying to simply launch a third part app when when the ok button is selected. I have the following code but it's not coming together. I'm a novice at this and can't quite figure it out.

```
        public class Abc extends Activity {

static final String MARKET_SEARCH_Q_PNAME_ANDRIOS = "market://search?q=pname:com.3rdparty.app";



@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.getpft);
    setTitle("Install 3rd party app?");

    ((Button) findViewById(R.id.Ok)).setOnClickListener(new Openabc());
    ((Button) findViewById(R.id.FindIt)).setOnClickListener(new FindZxingOnclickListener());
}


public class Openabc implements OnClickListener {
    public void onClick(View v) {
        Intent i = new Intent("android.intent.action.MAIN");
        i.addCategory("android.intent.category.LAUNCHER");
        i.setPackage("com.3rdparty.app");
        startActivity(i);
    }}


public class FindZxingOnclickListener implements OnClickListener {
    public void onClick(View v) {
        Intent marketLaunch = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
        marketLaunch.setData(Uri.parse(MARKET_SEARCH_Q_PNAME_ANDRIOS));
        startActivity(marketLaunch);
    }}
```

}

Comment: Once you've created the intent, you're calling `startActivity(Intent)`, which does nothing.

Answer (score 2):

In short, you're not building the intent correctly.

[Here](http://code.google.com/p/zxing/wiki/ScanningViaIntent) is an example of launching another activity via an intent. The thing to pay special attention to is the way that they build the intent.

I can't really help without knowing the specifics of the intent you're trying to hit, but here is the meat of the link:

```
    Intent intent = new Intent("com.3rdpartydev.abcapp.GO");
    intent.setPackage("com.3rdpartydev.abcapp");
    startActivity(intent);
```

that'll tell Android to look for something that knows how to handle com.3rdpartydev.abcapp.GO requests, and if it can find it, launch it.

I'd suggest re-reading [this](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html) for more information

Comment: to handle the case of "if it's not installed", you wrap the call to startActivity in a try/catch block, and if you catch the exception that's thrown when there isn't an app present, you should start the market activity with the search for that specific app that you're looking to install. If you don't get anywhere with this, I can post more code this evening that does exactly that.

Comment: Lawn if you could provide an example that would be fantastic. What you've provided me with has been great I will try and figure how to fit it all together.

Comment: Is there documentation you could share? perhaps if I saw what it was you were trying to do, I could give you a better answer.

Comment: My app has a section that depends on another app that's in the market. The page that's up is a simple screen that provides two buttons. The "get it" button searches the market and allows the user to download the app. 

The end goal. Is to build this page so that after the app is already installed, the page automatically brings the user to the other app. I know I'm still kind of far off from that, but my first step was to just get the "OK" button to open the partner app and that's where I'm at now. If you have a contact email I can send you the apk if you'd like to see it.

Answer (score 1):

I haven't done Android for a while, but looking through the documentation quickly, I'm thinking this is the problem:

Your class isn't actually going to do anything, because it doesn't make use (via inheritance or composition) of any Android classes. Once you create the `Intent`, you're calling an empty method, so nothing is going to happen. The easiest way to make this work is to delete the definition for `private void startActivity(Intent i)`, and move the other stuff to your `Activity` class. Have that class implement `OnClickListener` if you need it, and then call the built in `startActivity` method.

Comment: parkovski, I understand how that makes more sense. I moved my intent into the main activity class and it should run when the OK button is selected. However that intent itself must be missconstructed because it force closes. Any ideas?

This is really just a part of the big picture. That is that I want the class to check if the 3rd part app is installed. If it's not then they search the market and install it. Afterwards when they come to this page I want that app to automatically open in mine. I am using the correct package name in my intent so I'm a bit lost. 
Thanks